# Error while using cpan command line

Tags: perl, cpan, activeperl

I am getting the below errors while using cpan command line:

```
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz'
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not
contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9741)
Warning: Your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz does not
contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
........Could not split line["            return \"DIRECT\";"]
Could not split line[""]
........Could not split line["            return \"DIRECT\";"]
Could not split line[""]
Giving up parsing your C:\Perl64\cpan\sources\modules\02packages.details.txt.gz,
 too many errors
```

I was trying to install cpanm using cpan App::cpanminus command in command prompt.

I am behind a firewall and have configured the pac file in the http_proxy env variable also. I am using ActivePerl.

Comment: Anyone faced the same problem? I am still facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`return "DIRECT";` is something you will often see in a proxy configuration file, so that's what you probably downloaded into `02packages.details.txt.gz` before your proxy was set up correctly.

Once you're sure that your proxy is set up correctly, delete this file and run `cpan` again. Then `cpan` will download a fresh copy of the package file.

---

> Once you're sure that your proxy is set up correctly ...

`cpan` has proxy settings that may need to be configured to get this working.
Run `o conf /proxy/` from the cpan prompt to see them.

On my work machine, for example, I have the settings

```
http_proxy     [http://proxymachine.mycompany.com:82]
no_proxy       [localhost,127.0.0.1,internalsite.mycompany.com]
```

Comment: I have made the proxy settings only in the env variables and not in any perl config file. Can the error be caused by that??

Comment: As I tried deleting this file but the one being downloaded also throws the same error

Comment: Did you do the settting in both the conf file and the env variables

Comment: Also cpan is not using my local home config i think when I call cpan